# DocumentDB query nested object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having trouble querying nested objects in DocumentDB. I have no control over the format of the data. Let's say an object looks like this in DocumentDB:

```
{
    "SCHEMA_ID": {
        "PROJECT": "A",
        "MODEL": "B",
        "GUID":"A GUID"
    },
    "STATE": {
        "Active": "True"
    },
    "OBJECTS": {
        "OBJECT": [
            {
                "ATTR_VALS": {
                    "NAME": "Header",
                    "ID": "0",
                    "VALUE": [
                        {
                            "NAME": "JobId",
                            "VAL": "1011656"
                        },
                        {
                            "NAM": "Region",
                            "VAL": "West Coast"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "ATTR_VALS": {
                    "NAME": "SampleData",
                    "ID": "0",
                    "VALUE": [
                        {
                            "NAME": "Height",
                            "VAL": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "NAM": "Length",
                            "VAL": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to find all the objects that have a 'ATTR_VALS' = 'SampleData' and where those items have a 'Height'=5

So Far I have:

```
SELECT test.GUID
FROM test
join OBJECTS in test.OBJECTS
join OBJECT in OBJECTS
join ATTR_VALS in OBJECT
join VALUE in ATTR_VALS
WHERE ATTR_VALS.NAME = 'SampleData' AND VALUE.NAME='Height' AND   VALUE.VAL='5'
```

But this doesn't work, and returns no results. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get results when you click "Next Page"? Some queries might not return results in the first page(s), but will return results in subsequent pages.

Comment: @AravindRamachandran I get 0 results back. I am running the query in .net code. Similar code with no joins returns data fine (like SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.GUID = 'A GUID')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query must be:

```
SELECT test.SCHEMA_ID.GUID
FROM test
join OBJ in test.OBJECTS.OBJECT
join VAL in OBJ.ATTR_VALS["VALUE"]
WHERE OBJ.ATTR_VALS.NAME = "SampleData" AND VAL.NAME='Height' AND VAL.VAL='5'
```

A couple things I changed:

- JOIN must be performed against arrays, not objects. Objects can be expanded using the “.” Operator
- VALUE is a special keyword and must be escaped
- Small typo in the projection clause missing SCHEMA_ID